# How to create a customized swipe-able calendar in android using gridview?

Tags: android, gridview, calendar

I want to create a customized calendar in which I can show events on particular date. And need to make it swipe-able to change month.I want to create it using view pager.But I don't know how view pager will create different layout for different different month or years as they are countless in calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/dbrain/android-calendarview. Probably it is the thing you are looking for.